# Will admin on rest play nicely with cloudinary/postgres on the same tab?

Tags: reactjs, cloudinary, admin-on-rest

Before i start looking down this road i have different datasources that would need to be updated in the same tab if i was to attempt to use react-admin, wondering if i'll be able to modify it to do what i need?

Comment: I think it would be best if you showed us what you have tried and if you have encountered any issues.

Comment: I was actually looking to find out beforehand if i was going to run into trouble trying to use react admin with the necessity of needing a cloudinary react drop zone along with the default functionality supplied when it comes to creating say an article where most of that info goes off to postgres. I ask because i checked it out before but not in depth enough to go beyond default behaviour, i'll happily go down the road and and stumble through getting it to work, just don't have time to hit a dead end is all. Your response probably means you see no reason why it shouldn't work?

Comment: it occurs to me that you may be speaking strictly from the Cloudinary side in which case i can't see it being an issue, it's more the react admin side that looks to me like it might be an issue where alot of this functionality is out of the box

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else who happened to land here and had as little experience as i did when i asked this.... you can use the cloudinary widget in your react-admin app and pass the returned url off to your mutation no problem.